# Hyper-V on Windows 11 no longer allows network adapter to function in virtual hosts

Tags: windows, hyper-v

Everything was working great until Windows 11 rebooting and installed the latest update (a fair amount of changes visually).

I re-opened my hypervisor and started my MS Server 2022 for my dev environment.  It came up ok but I wasn't able to connect to it.  I opened a command prompt and saw that it wasn't getting an IP.  I tried shutting the network adapter down and restarting it, issuing an ipconfig /renew, and restarting the server to no avail.  I'm not seeing any error messages.

Firewall is turned off on hyper-v host as well as client.

I also started a windows 10 virtual host and it also had the same issue so I'm thinking it's hyper-v...

Any ideas on what I can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up deleting the NICs in the Hyper-V switch manager, recreating them, then re-assigned them to the virtual hosts on this computer.